# Hover doesn't work with bigger height

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, hover

I have a problem with [my eshop](http://gtwatch.cz/objednavka.php). There are a boxes with products and at that boxes is hover and JS onlick. It works fine, but only for boxes, which are visible on device-height. At boxes, for which you must scroll down it doesn't work. Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little **CSS** trick will save your day! Here it is:

```
.inside {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: I'll give it too.  Good answer.  He can also just remove `position: relative` from `.inside`